# FFMPEG converts HEVC with Alpha mov to PNG sequence not work well

Tags: ffmpeg, video, alpha, hevc

I have a mov file with HEVC with Alpha codec on Mac. The mov file has no background color, but have some foreground contents in it. I want to use FFMPEG to grab some PNG pictures from it. Following is the command line I used to grab the first image from the video.

**ffmpeg -i hevc-alpha-video.mov -r 1 -pix_fmt rgba -frames:v 1 out.png**

I can get the output PNG picture. But it has black background color. What I want is the transparent background PNG picture.

Do you have any idea to handle this? Thanks.

Comment: Just hit the same issue, logged a bug on https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/10901